# Thymeleaf flash(swf)issue

Tags: thymeleaf

```
<body>

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="file3.swf" 
id="applicationID" style="margin:0 50px;width:auto;height:auto;">

<param name="movie" value="file3.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> <!-- Or opaque, etc. -->


<param name="FlashVars" value="" />

<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />

</object>

</body>
```

This is my thymeleaf page here file3.swf is the file i want play .
But when i run the page the flash does not play..!

Comment: Doesn't seem to have anything to do with thymeleaf. Check that all your parameters are correct or if you are missing any.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to show flash file in bowser, I assume that its correctly done :p

Have you check the firebug to see how its rendered ?